# Consuming API XML into csv file C#

Tags: c#, xml, api

I have the following XML in an API
[image]

I wish to read the data from the tags and build a CSV file with the values.

My code so far,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://localhost:5001/api/Scheduler/GetScheduler";

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            try
            {
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
                    try
                    {
                        xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
                        Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.Root.Element("ORD_NAME").Value);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        // handle if necessary
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                // handle if necessary    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the data being read in, but xmlDoc, but xmlDoc.Root.Element("ORD_NAME").Value is NULL.
How do I get the data from the stream?

Thanks.

Comment: The "rows" are the "Scheduler" elements, no? Your code doesn't seem to select them at all so you rather want to process `xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Scheduler")` to map to a row or line of your CSV, then read out each child element or only specific ones like `ORD_NAME` as values.

Comment: Thanks, xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Scheduler") gives me the values I want, but how do I get at them, so I can build an csv file.  Do I need to foreach loop on xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Scheduler")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want e.g

```
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", from row in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Scheduler") select string.Join(";", row.Elements().Select(e => e.Value))));
            }
```

.NET probably has some better APIs to construct CSVs than using LINQ to XML directly, the above will fail to quote value or escape separators.